# Powershell Factory Pattern as static method

Tags: powershell, factory-pattern

I am looking to implement a tool that can manage files with a variety of locations; local files, UNC path files, files hosted on AWS, files hosted on a Synology NAS, etc. This will be done in PS 5.1 using classes and a number of specific patterns.

My thinking is I need a base path type, that has a property for the path itself. Then I need classes for UNC paths, local paths, AWS paths etc. that inherit form the base Path class. Then I can have a Copy class that handles the copy differently depending on the method signature. So UNC > UNC is handled differently from AWS > UNC. So, Strategy Pattern.

As for the path types, this seems like a place for the Factory Pattern. And every single example I have found on the internet for the Factory Pattern, in PowerShell, involves a dedicated Factory class. But it seems to me that logically, the Factory to create Path derivatives could/should be part of the Path class itself, as a static method. I searched on static factory method, and the concept is well documented for other languages, but not PowerShell. So I decided to just try it. To that end, I have this as a proof of concept...

```
class pxPath {
    hidden $_path
    
    pxPath () {}
    pxPath ([string]$path) {
        $this._path = $path
    }

    static [pxPath] Factory ([String]$path) {
        [pxPath]$newPath = [uncFileSystem]::new($path)

        return $newPath
    }
}

class uncFileSystem : pxPath {
    
    uncFileSystem ([String]$path) : base ([String]$path) {
    }
}

$testPath = [pxPath]::Factory('\\Server\folder\file.txt')
$testPath.getType().FullName
$testPath._path
```

It doesn't have the multiple derived types needed for the Strategy Pattern, it just creates the one derived type. But it proves that a Factory as static method works.

My question is, is there some argument against this that I am not seeing, that explains why I have never seen an example like this for PowerShell? It makes SO much sense to me, and yet I have never seen it done, which really gives me pause.

Comment: Maybe you should look into [Powershell Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/prog-guide/how-to-create-a-windows-powershell-provider?view=powershell-5.1). The docs have details how to [design your own provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/prog-guide/designing-your-windows-powershell-provider?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: @zett42 Ah, that's an interesting though I didn't even realize was possible. Some more holiday reading I see! :) The original question does still stand, as I have another situation in which a Factory pattern plays a part. But perhaps that ends ups being the only place I need it.

Comment: Whether it makes sense depends entirely on purpose. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I guess, really the goal vis-a-vis static Factory method or dedicated Factory class is, understandability down the line. As far as I can tell both work, and it's maybe just the fact that IN MY MIND, having the factory as a static method in the parent class makes some logical sense. The only real question is, is there something unusual about Powershell, and specifically it's implementation of classes, that argues against. There are places where PS classes are... odd, and things that work in other OOP languages don't work here.

Comment: Yes, a lot of things are unusual about PowerShell - Factory Patterns make very little sense because you're always "bringing your own source code" to the runtime - alleviating the need to observe a number of design considerations (said another way: observing SOLID principles in a language that has limited support for the I and D and little use for the O is... sort of silly)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Interesting, so do I understand right you don't see much value in Factory methods in general? This may be a "new post" level tangent, but I wonder about your thoughts on my other situation. I have 20 to eventually 30+ "tasks" where lots of characteristics are shared between all of them. They are defined from data in XML files, so my thought was a Task class with the shared aspects and a Factory static method, that would accept the XML node as argument and return the correct initialized child type. In any case, SOLID is a new concept for me. Off to wikipedia! ;)

Comment: I see _some_ value in Factory Patterns implemented in scenarios where you compile the base abstractions and someone else extends the code base by adding new factories as they define new concrete types on top. But in PowerShell, that makes no sense, because compile-time = run-time. By "limited support for  I[nterface segregation] and D[ependency Inversion]" I'm referring to the fact that we can't write interface (or similar explicitly abstract) types directly in PowerShell. Ping me on twitter if you want to talk design patterns in the abstract (comments are not fit for this)